# MVC Route and Angular

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-routing, mvcroutehandler

I am facing a problem that is driving me crazy. I will try to be simple about the issue.

I have a project that uses MVC and Angular. The project has a page layout to signin and another to use in main project. I can't change the way the users access the pages, so I need to create the routes the same way they are using.

I want to change the mvc route to use different actions to use the correct layout, one is for signin and the other layout to the main app. The examples below:

- To access the signin page: {mainurl}/#/signin
- To access another signin page, but for support, using the same layout as signin: {mainurl}/#/signinsupport
- To access the main page, after signin: {mainurl}/#/main

How can I change the mvc route to access these different pages using the urls above? Is there an easy way to do that?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Create your route in route provider

Comment: why can't you use normal angular routes?

Comment: I have created in route provider, but I don't know how to force to use these different urls for each one... about the angular route, I have tried to use as well, but I need to change the page, I mean the layout, and the angular route changes a part of the page, it doesn't update the layout page, I mean the whole page.. or, if you know a way to do that, it will help me a lot!